# Eclipse Juno subversive {root_prefix} label decorator does not work

Tags: eclipse-juno, eclipse-indigo, subversive

Subversive {root_prefix} label decorator does not work in my Juno.
It worked fine in my Indigo.

Could anyone confirm {root_prefix} works in your Juno?

I really miss this feature to see whether I am working on trunk or branch or tag in package explorer.  It seems like IntelliJ does not offer it yet :)

Answer (score 2):

I've had issues with this as well, hence I changed the text decoration for projects to the following:
{outgoing_flag} {name} {revision} [{short_url}]

The {short_url} variable is substituted with a concise label. E.g. "branches/HelloWorld".

Comment: Thanks Max for the workaround!  I hope subversive dev could address it in the future.

Comment: The latest version seems fixed the issue.  Thanks to subversive developers!  Subversive SVN Connectors Version: 3.0.1.I20130331-1700

Answer (score 0):

The latest version seems fixed the issue. Thanks to subversive developers! Subversive SVN Connectors Version: 3.0.1.I20130331-1700